This BATCH code with regex never is true, what could be wrong?
I'd like to know what here is wrong for the code never be TRUE.
the rest here is working fine.
...
(echo !currPdfName! | findstr /r "^[0-9]\{8\}_[0-9]\{11\}_[0-9]\{9\}_[0-9]\{1\}\.pdf$" >nul) && (
SET MKTPlaceCode=!MKTCodeStringCASASBAHIA!
echo "MKTPlaceCode set to: !MKTPlaceCode!"
pause
)
...
the rest here is also OK, working fine.

Remembering that I'm using the
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

before this code, because i need for other purposes.
What could be wrong. The file name is: 20241101_44148280602_000000417_1.pdf
As you can see. the file name is in the correct name for matching  the abox regex expression.
But even the name being correct. the script gives FALSE...
I maybe am addicted with the code so that I can't see the mistake!!
I also tried (without parenthesis):
echo !currPdfName! | findstr /r "^[0-9]\{8\}_[0-9]\{11\}_[0-9]\{9\}_[0-9]\{1\}\.pdf$" >nul && (
SET MKTPlaceCode=!MKTCodeStringCASASBAHIA!
echo "MKTPlaceCode set to: !MKTPlaceCode!"
pause
)
            


One solution is:
echo !currPdfName!| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /R "^[12][09][01234-9][01234-9][01][01234-9][0123][01234-9]_[01234-9][01234-9]*_[01234-9][01234-9]*_[01234-9]\.pdf$
It is advisable reading the usage help or documentation of a command on something is not working as expected. The usage help of a Windows command can be read by opening a command prompt and running the command with /? as argument which means in this case findstr /?. The execution of the command help in the command prompt window outputs an incomplete list of Windows commands with a brief description. The A-Z index of Windows CMD commands on SS64 offers information about Windows commands which cannot be found in the usage helps or Microsoft’s online documentation of the Windows commands.
The regular expression syntax of the more than 30 years old and never enhanced Windows command FINDSTR is known nowadays as Perl compatible regular expression syntax, but the supported regular expressions are very limited as it can be read in the usage help. Multipliers like {x} or {x,y} are not supported at all by FINDSTR. The characters { and } are interpreted literally. The character classes must be repeated themselves in the search expression.
There are some more differences between the regular expression interpretation of FINDSTR and those in modern text editors using Perl compatible regular expression libraries like the Boost regular expression library for regular expression finds and replaces.
The character class [0-9] used in a FINDSTR regular expression matches 0123456789¹²³ and not just 0123456789 as by the Perl compatible regular expression searches of other programs. It is necessary to use [0123456789] or [01234-9] for excluding the characters ¹²³.
The length of the search expression is limited. FINDSTR outputs an error message if the search expression is too long. Repeating [0123456789] or [01234-9] multiple times for the file name scheme in the search expression would result in a too long search expression.
ECHO is different to most Windows commands. It interprets a space character not as argument separator but as character to output too. A space character left to the redirection operator | is output for that reason also by the command ECHO. The expression part \.pdf$ results never in a positive match on file name is passed with a trailing space to FINDSTR. The solution is using echo !currPdfName!| with no space left to the redirection operator |.
20241101 is obviously a date string in format yyyyMMdd. The regular expression above considers that although with possible false positive matches on file name having an invalid date.
The first two digits are for the century. It is expected that the centuries are only 1900 and 2000. [12][09] matches 19 and 20 and of course also the false positives 10 and 29. In a full Perl compatible search expression would be used (?:19|20) for matching the two digits of the century at the beginning of the file name. But such a non-capturing OR expression is not supported by FINDSTR which is the reason for using [12][09] which also matches the centuries 1000 and 2900.
The two digits of the year are matched with [01234-9][01234-9] which means matched are all the years from 00 to 99 within the century.
[01][01234-9] matches the two digits of the month. That expression includes not only the valid month values 01 to 12 but also the invalid month values 00 and 13 to 19. In a full Perl compatible search expression would be used (?:0[1-9]|1[012]) for matching the two digits of the month with excluding invalid month values.
[0123][01234-9] matches the two digits of the day in month which is a value in range 01 to 31 depending on month and for month 02 also on year (leap year). That simple expression matches of course lots of invalid day values too. But the search expression is not for validating the date in file name for this task.
[01234-9][01234-9]* is for matching an ASCII digit one or more times. That is most likely enough for this task for excluding file names of wrong file name scheme.
The regular expression is applied case-insensitive due to option /I as a PDF file name could have as file extension among .pdf also .PDF or other unusual spellings like .pDf.
